# use str_replace for a single variable

Tags: php, str-replace

how would i use str_replace to replace all '.' in a variable to '-', for a single variable?

so for example

```
$var1 = 'hello.world';
$var2 = // somehow use str_replace to change . to - for content of var1?
print var2;
```

would output:  'hello-world'.

From my reading it looks like str_replace would be the best thing to do this but i cant work out how. If there is a different/better way i would be glad to learn that too.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: [str_replace](http://us1.php.net/str-replace) php docs tell you how to use it

Comment: What's wrong with `$var2 = str_replace('.', '-', $var1);`? Keep in mind that the search pattern is _not_ a regex.

Comment: You obviously found the function `str_replace()`, did you give up after that or what? I recommend you read [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use str_replace. 1st parameter is the string to find, 2nd is the one to replace it with and 3rd is the parameter to look at.

```
$var1 = 'hello.world';
$var2 = str_replace(".", "-", $var1);
echo $var2; // hello-world
```